# How to set environment variables automatically?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alias

So I do research in machine learning and use a remote GPU server to do the stuff. What I usually do when I come to work is access the server with an SSH client and run my alias `hi` command which is:

```
alias hi='conda activate userconda; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1; alias hi'
```

The server is usually shared among two to three people and has two GPU's, each with ID `0` or `1`.

What I'm wondering is, would there be some kind of way to automatically determine which GPU ID to assign to the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` based on which GPU isn't being used? Right now my alias is hard coded to be `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`, but it would be more convenient if the program could do that automatically.

I was thinking maybe there could be a way to use the output of `nvidia-smi`, but I'm not sure if that would be the right approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia smi reports you the bus ofthe active video card:

```
nvidia-smi 
Sat Apr 11 04:02:56 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 45%   33C    P8    11W / 175W |    252MiB /  7974MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1089      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           106MiB |
|    0      1355      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                             79MiB |
|    0      1361      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               2MiB |
|    0      1364      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                          56MiB |
|    0      5152      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So: **00000000:01:00.0  On** is the device bus. So  you can run nvidia-smi grep for this result and assing the other device whose bus you can get by lspci.